# Merge Two Sorted Arrays in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have two sorted arrays

```
array1 = [0, 3, 4, 31]
array2 = [4, 6, 30]
```

I try to sort these arrays by using the code below:

```
def mergeSortedArray(array1, array2):
    if not len(array1):
        return array2

    if not len(array2):
        return array1


    mergedArray = []
    array1Item = array1[0]
    array2Item = array2[0]
    i = 0
    j = 0

    while (i < len(array1)) and (j < len(array2)):

        if array1Item < array2Item:
            mergedArray.append(array1Item)
            array1Item = array1[i + 1]
            i += 1
        else:
            mergedArray.append(array2Item)
            print(j)
            array2Item = array2[j + 1]
            j += 1

    return mergedArray

print(mergeSortedArray([0, 3, 4, 31], [4, 6, 30]))
```

But the terminal keep telling me that:

```
line 26, in mergeSortedArray
    array2Item = array2[j + 1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I wonder which part I did wrong! Can someone explain to me? plz~

BTW, what is the syntactically cleanest way to accomplish this?

Comment: you have `while i < len(array1)` but then you reference `array1[i+1]`.  Just try `array1[len(array1)+1]` index is inherently more than length of your list.  The index of lists in python starts at 0.

Comment: Also try to provide sample output of what you're trying to achieve.  You mention you want to sort but your function is called merge.  you sorting and merging

Answer (score 1):

Make use of Python's features, such as merging two lists with the `+` operator. Then, simply sort the new list.

```
>>> array1 = [0, 3, 4, 31]
>>> array2 = [4, 6, 30]
>>> merged_array = array1 + array2
>>> merged_array.sort()
>>> merged_array
[0, 3, 4, 4, 6, 30, 31]
```

Answer (score 0):

before assigning the `array1` and `array2` next index value to `array1Item` and `array2Item` check if do they exist or not.

check the first array next index that it has a value or no.

```
 if i+1<len(array1):
    array1Item = array1[i + 1]
```

also check the second array next index value.

```
if j+1 < len(array2):
   array2Item = array2[j + 1]
```

**Note1:** Each Array of our function may have deferent length. Once the comparison is finished and there is no value to compare in one of the arrays، we need to add the remaining values in the latter array to "mergedArray".

```
def mergeSortedArray(array1, array2):
  if not len(array1):
      return array2

  if not len(array2):
      return array1

  mergedArray = [] 

  array1Item = array1[0]
  array2Item = array2[0]
  i = 0
  j = 0

  while (i < len(array1)) and (j < len(array2)):

      if array1Item < array2Item:
          mergedArray.append(array1Item)
          if i+1<len(array1):
              array1Item = array1[i + 1]
          i += 1
      else:
          mergedArray.append(array2Item)
          if j+1 < len(array2):
              array2Item = array2[j + 1]
          j += 1

  return mergedArray+array1[i:]+array2[j:]
print(mergeSortedArray([0, 12,19,26,4431], [4, 16, 30,40,111,134]))
```

**Note2:** for cleaner code even you do not need the `array1Item` and `array2Item` variable, your directly use the `mergedArray.append(array1[i])`
instead of

```
array1Item = array1[0]
 mergedArray.append(array1Item)
 if i+1<len(array1):
     array1Item = array1[i + 1]
```

clean code.

```
def mergeSortedArray(array1, array2):
    if not len(array1):
        return array2

    if not len(array2):
        return array1


    mergedArray = []
    array1Item = array1[0]
    array2Item = array2[0]
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(array1) and j < len(array2):
         if array1[i] < array2[j]:
           mergedArray.append(array1[i])
           i += 1
         else:
           mergedArray.append(array2[j])
           j += 1
    return mergedArray+ array1[i:] + array2[j:]
```